# Decode images from Sdcard Asynchronously - Image not appearing

Tags: android, image, gridview, asynchronous, bitmapfactory

I have been facing a real hard time trying to discover how to display images from my internal storage without having both lag and bugs ... I Googled a lot , and got a few answers to my previous questions , but now I'm really getting desperate .

So here is my problem , I want to make a gallery like app , using a simple gridView , and imageViews , however , when I first launch the app , the grid looks empty (I have 100 images in the gridview for testing) , when I scroll , the images down appear , when I scroll back up to the start , the images appear again ! I tried tinkering my code , and the result was that they appeared , but the app laggedd , since it wasn't decoding asynchronously ... Here are the related methods and stuff :

My onCreate() :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);

        TwoWayGridView grid = (TwoWayGridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        grid.setNumColumns(2);
        grid.setAdapter(new GirdAdapter());

    }
```

My Adapter :

```
class GirdAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 100;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

            RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.image_view, null); // Just a conatianer
            ImageView image = (ImageView) r.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) r.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

            imageButton.setVisibility(View.GONE); // I don't need this button now


            String pic = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20131225_183622.jpg" ; // This is an absolute path to an image on my internal storage

            image.setImageBitmap(getProperBitmap(pic, 200, 200 , GalleryActivity.this)); 

            return r;
        }

    }
```

Method for asynchronous decoding :

```
public static Bitmap getProperBitmap(final String imagePath , final int reqHeight , final int reqWidth ){



        AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> background = new AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap>() {

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

                BitmapFactory.Options options = new Options();

                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true ;

                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

                int height = options.outHeight ;
                int width = options.outWidth ;

                int inSampleSize = 1;

                if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

                    final int halfHeight = height / 2;
                    final int halfWidth = width / 2;

                    // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
                    // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
                    while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                            && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                        inSampleSize *= 2;
                    }


                }

                options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize ;

                options.inJustDecodeBounds = false ;



                result = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

                GalleryActivity.result = result ;

                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }


        }.execute("");


        return result ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is almost stable , however , to get the image to be displayed , you have to call `image.setImageBitmap` once the AsyncTask is done ...

To do that , you have to add an ImageView parameter to your `getProperBitmap` method , and when calling this method , assign the ImageView that you wish to use ...

So it would be like this :

```
public static Bitmap getProperBitmap(final String imagePath , final int reqHeight , final int reqWidth , ImageView v)
```

Then , at the end of the Asynchronous task , at the onPostExecute , set the image ! so it would be like :

```
@Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

                GalleryActivity.result = result ;

                v.setImageBitmap(result) ;

                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }
```

And with this , everything will work just fine !